# Hostels in Vienna - reservation and prepaid

Tags: bookings, hostels, austria, vienna

I'm planning to spend a few days in Vienna, in hostel, 2 person. I haven't started looking for hostel, so I have the question about the specific of finding hostel there:

1. Do I need a reservation at all to get there in September? I was in Berlin in August, without reservation, and I've found free place in first of the hostels
2. If I need, how much in advance I need to reserve? A week, a month?
3. Is the prepaid necessary when making reservation, or I pay everything after arrival?

Comment: Are you just after a random bed in a dorm, or are you after a bed in a small room at a fun and friendly nice hostel? (The former will be available long after the latter is all booked out!)

Answer (score 3):

Vienna is a popular tourist destination, with many hostels. You will be able to find the beds(probably in different rooms), if you leave it till the last minute; or you might not. Popular hostels like St Christopher's Inn get booked out pretty soon.

It is best to book in advance, I would say. Having said that, it is never advisable to book way in advance, as the rates seem to be higher then (Personal Experience). Best to book it a week or 10 days before. There are many booking sites - [www.hostelbookers.com](http://www.hostelbookers.com) is a good one. However, it is better if you book directly with the hostel (you will most probably get the cheapest rates).

When you book in through a booking site, a 10% deposit is required. If you book it directly with the hostel, you might not be required to pay the deposit.